Struggling with the conversion of a xml file into a xliff file
I am struggling to translate this xml file:
<document>
<metadata_list>
<metadata status="translating" type="doc_title">Document to translate</metadata>
</metadata_list>
<content>
<para id="para151374285">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">Título</para_content>
</para>
<para align="justify" id="para667863099">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">traducción a mano</para_content>
</para>
<para align="justify" id="para224593780">
<para_content lang="de-DE"/>
</para>
<para id="titleimage145389846">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">Imágen de ejemplo</para_content>
</para>
<para id="para650497377">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">1</para_content>
</para>
<para id="para252996714">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">uno</para_content>
</para>
<para id="para264174280">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">2</para_content>
</para>
<para id="para159549621">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">dos</para_content>
</para>
<para id="para751025178">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">3</para_content>
</para>
<para id="para733768577">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">tres</para_content>
</para>
<para align="justify" id="para734026856">
<para_content lang="de-DE"/>
</para>
<para align="justify" id="para516785049">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">Traducción de párrafo</para_content>
</para>
<para align="justify" id="para581804402">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">Traducción de párrafo</para_content>
</para>
<para align="justify" id="para182264526" modified="5">
<para_content lang="de-DE"/>
</para>
<para id="titleimage272840667" modified="5">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">imágen de prueba</para_content>
</para>
<para align="justify" id="para979668678" modified="5">
<para_content lang="de-DE"/>
</para>
<para align="justify" id="para127940730">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">Traducción de párrafo</para_content>
</para>
<para align="justify" id="para750127719">
<para_content lang="de-DE" status="translating">Traducción de párrafo</para_content>
</para>
</content>
</document>

The translation tool I use keeps telling me that "The file does not have any valid segments. If you are using a custom-made XML, please consider using XLIFF 1.2 instead". Then they recommend "writing a piece of software that converts the xml file into XLIFF 1.2 and then vice versa". I am learning to code, but I am not so advanced. Can someone help me about the necessary steps to do it? Thank you in advance.

Forget the tools.  What does the application want to see as an input.  XLIFF is xml in a standard format so you do not need to translate to XLIFF.  Just modify the existing XML to an XML that the application can read.

Thanks @jdweng, the problem is that I don't have access to the original application that generates the XML.
Here is the whole explanation: My customer produces XML files with an application that they use (I don't have access to it). Then they send the XML file to me. I have to translate only the content. And my translation tool is not able to extract that content, it says "The file does not have any valid segments. If you are using a custom-made XML, please consider using XLIFF 1.2 instead". That is why I want to convert the XML file into a XLIFF 1.2 file that my translation tool could read.
